# Call controls inside view(xaml file) in viewmodel

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I want to call controls inside view like button and item template inside viewmodel. Please tell how can I do that. My view contains following

```
<ItemsControl Name="cDetails"
            Width="395"
            ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource Test}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}"
            Visibility="{Binding IsLoaded,
                                Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">

    <Button Name="btnComplete"
        Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Command="{Binding AuditCommand}"
        CommandParameter="1">
        Complete
    </Button>
```

Please tell how can I call these items in my viewmodel using vb.net.

Thanks

Comment: You can't directly. Depending what you want to achive, binding to properties in the VM is usually the way to go. What exactly do you need to do?

Comment: I am calling to click event of the button in viewmodel, there I want to access the this button and ItemControl

Comment: In that case pass the Button itself via the CommandParameter to your command: `CommandParameter={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`. I assume you have something like a RelayCommand in your VM, which takes the CommandParameter as generic Type parameter: `RelayCommand<Button>`

Comment: no i have not used RelayCommand. How can I do that can u please help me with the code

Comment: See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx), Figure 3. If you don't want to implement your own, you can simply use MVVMLight, which has it already build-in.

Comment: Passing the Button as a parameter violates the MVVM pattern... All code that needs to access the view implementation (controls, etc.) has to be in the view, be it XAML or code-behind.

Comment: Avoid passing controls like that if at all possible. *Why* are you trying to pass the controls to the ViewModel? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing your view components from inside your viewmodel is not the way to do things in MVVM. Because it is specifically not designed to work this way, you will have to go out of your way to make it work. You should probably investigate how to accomplish your goals using MVVM properly, or forego using MVVM at all and do the work in your code-behind.

Since you have not described what your goal is, it is hard to provide specific recommendations. In general when using MVVM, you manipulate things in your viewmodel and set properties. Your view binds to these properties so that it updates appropriately as they are being set. Your viewmodel does not directly manipulate the views themselves, only the viewmodel properties that they are bound to.

For example, let's say you are updating the text on a `TextBlock`. You could do something like this in xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeText}" />
```

Then, your viewmodel (which should [implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229614.aspx)) defines this property and sets it as desired.

```
public string SomeText
{
    get { return _someText; }
    set
    {
        if (_someText != value)
        {
            _someText = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SomeText");
        }
    }
}
private string _someText;

...

// At any time, you can set the property, and the
// binding will update the text in the control for you.
SomeText = "Some text";
```

If you absolutely need to manipulate your views from code (or if you are not using MVVM), the appropriate place for that sort of code is the "xaml.cs" file next to your view (the code-behind). You can assign a name to anything in your xaml using syntax like `<TextBlock x:Name="SomeTextBlock" />` and then access it from the code-behind as a member variable with the same name. For example, you could do `SomeTextBlock.Text = "Some text"`. However, this is not usually necessary for the vast majority of use cases if you are using MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to access controls directly from the ViewModel. The ViewModel must not know about the View implementation.

Instead, in WPF we connect View and ViewModel through Bindings. Bindings connect Properties of controls in the View, with Properties in the ViewModel.

Commands are a special type of Property that can be bound as actions for controls like Button.

In your example, you would need to have these properties in your ViewModel:

- A collection named `ViewModels`
- A boolean named `IsLoaded`
- And an ICommand named `AuditCommand`

By managing those properties, you should be able to control what's shown in your View and its behavior.

If you need more control, create more Bindings to other properties, or create some events in your ViewModel and manage them from your View's code-behind.